# How to make "dplyr select" to use the value of the character parameter instead of its name as a literal?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple function for selecting one column from data frame.
Parameter "my_column" is a name of the column to select.
The function works bad when datafame contains a column named "my_column". Hereis an example:

````
library(dplyr)
select_one_column<-function(df,my_column) { select(df,my_column) }

df11 <- data.frame(
  var1 = c( 'good', 'good'),
  var2 = c( 'good2', 'good2') )

df22 <- data.frame(
  var1 = c( 'good', 'good'),
  var2 = c( 'good2', 'good2'),
  my_column=c('bad','bad') )

select_one_column(df11,"var1")```
````

Result:

var1

1 good

2 good

```
select_one_column(df22,'var1')
```

Result:

my_column

1       bad

2       bad

How to make "dplyr select"  to use the value of the character parameter instead of its name as a literal?

Comment: use `select_at` instead of `select` for character input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use `select`, one option is evaluate (`!!`)

```
select_one_column <- function(df, my_column) { 
           select(df, !!my_column)
   }

select_one_column(df11,"var1")
#  var1
#1 good
#2 good

select_one_column(df22,'var1')
#  var1
#1 good
#2 good
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution already works, you just have to make sure that your that the variable that you are using in the function cannot be column name of any dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

select_one_column<-function(df,string_which_cannot_be_column_name) {
     select(df,string_which_cannot_be_column_name) 
} 

select_one_column(df11,"var1")
#  var1
#1 good
#2 good

select_one_column(df22,"var1")
#  var1
#1 good
#2 good
```

---

As an alternative you can also look at curly-curly operator (`{{`)

```
select_one_column<-function(df,y)  select(df,{{y}})
```

which works with quoted column names

```
select_one_column(df11,"var1")
```

as well as unquoted ones.

```
select_one_column(df22,var1)
```